# Menu list issue in Visual studio 2022 community edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Visual Studio and the .NET framework. I create an ASP.NET Web API project and I a menu panel as shown in the screenshot, where  I can easily add the controller class and other stuff:

[image: Image with all menu]

but when I close Visual Studio and the reload the project, then I can not see the menu like in above, rather then I see the menu as shown below. I am confused - is this a setup problem or not?

[image: menu after reloading]

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: In your second screenshot, you're in "Solution Explorer - **Folder View**" - therefore the menu looks different. You should be able to toggle between the "real" solution explorer view (as in your first screenshot), and the folder view. Once you're back in "real" solution explorer, you should see the same menus again. Did you reopen your project by using "open folder" in VS - or did you open the actual `.csproj` project file?

Comment: I checked - the icon to toggle is the fourth icon from the left just under the "Solution Explorer" title bar - that looks like a form with the Visual Studio logo in its lower left corner. That allows you to toggle between different views

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s said, in the second screenshot, you entered "Solution Explorer - Folder View" by mistake.

There is a difference between the file page and the solution interface.

Click this button (Switch between solutions and available views), you can switch between different views.

[image]

[image]